# PHP table creation with name and score

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am having some serious trouble for some reason with creating a basic PhpMyAdmin database and making a page with a scoreboard. There will be a game that you play, and when you're done you can input a score and your name using basic form elements. When you press submit the page will reload and you will be able to see the top ten scores, ranked by highest first.

My issue is that I have no idea where to start with this. I have just started Php and don't wish for anything crazy. I have the ~/php/db_connect.php set up correctly already; I just need to make the function work.
How do you recommend I go through with this? Example code is extremely helpful.

I know the first response is "what have you tried?" and I haven't tried much.

This is what I have right now:

```
             // define variables and set to $name = $myArray[0];
            $babyinfo = fgets($myfile);
            $myfile = scoreboard-dk;
            $myArray = explode(',', );
            $score = $myArray[1];
            $name = $myArray[2];

            $insertStmt = "INSERT INTO scoreboard-dk ('score','name') VALUES ('$score','$name')";

          // Inserting Babynames into database

            $db->query($insertStmt);
        ?>
        <form action=" $db;?>" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=" echo $name;?>" required><br>
        Score: <input type="text" name="score-dk" value=" echo $score;?>" required><br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        </form>
        <tr> <th scope=row> echo $i;?></th> <td> echo $score;?></td> <td> echo $name;?></td> <td> echo $votes;?></td> </tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know how to turn on error reporting? I see a parse error right off the bat. Also, take a quick look at PDO and better escaping user variables.

Comment: "I haven't tried much"  Then you're not at the point where posting here is appropriate.

Comment: ^ Yeah, too broad as is. Need to ask specific questions.

Comment: @SpigAndromeda I don't think responding to someone trying to improve the quality of content on the site is productive. You certainly do not have to partake yourself if you object. Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251926/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-a-question-for-grammar-style-formatting

Answer (score 1):

Ok. First some mistakes you made:

`$myfile = scoreboard-dk;` isn't working. This way it would be a constant. You need the "$" or quotation marks if it should be a string.

`$myArray = explode(',', );` I don't know what you want to do? The second argument is missing. This statement won't work. Second argument has to be a string.

You have to properly escape the query before executing the statement. 
You can do this by replacing the following line before building the string:

```
$score = $db->real_escape_string($myArray[1]);
$name = $db->real_escape_string($myArray[2]);
```

Furthermore are you sure you use the correct indices for the array access? Counting starts with 0, not with 1.

You can't use PHP code without the opening tags. I thought that you cut that away at the start of the file. You always have to open PHP code blocks with

Perhaps you should search for example code elsewhere. I think stack is more for specific questions. But the code actually shows that you lack of some basic knowledge ... no offense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason people can't help you is that your question is way too broad and everyone will have a different approach about how to implement it.

That being said, here is the pseudo code I would use to implement this. It can be done in a single file. Good luck!

```
File: score_keeper.php

<?php
error_msg = array
if (form submitted)
    $name = name from form
    $score = score from form

    // Do validation to ensure name and score is as expected. 
    if name is empty
        error_msg[] = 'Name cannot be empty'

    if score is not numeric
        error_msg[] = 'Score must be numeric'

    if empty(error_msg)
        // INSERT
        // Make sure you use parameterized queries
        SQL = INSERT into table (name, score) VALUE (?, ?)
    end-if

end-if

// READ top 10
SQL = SELECT name, score FROM table WHERE ...

if !empty(error_msg)
    show error_msg
?>
<form method="post">
<input name="name">
<input name="score">
</form>

HTML table
<?php
// output top 10 results
```